# Erro CORS - Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, frontend, backend

Create an API with Nodejs to consume data in an application in parallel.
But when I use the fetch api in Javascript to consume the API that is running in http://localhost:3000/assistencias I always get a CORS error

I'm consuming the api with the following code, consuming it in `http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.html`

```js
async function getAll() {
  try {

    let url = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5501/assistencias`, {

      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    })
    let urlConvertida = await url.json();

    console.log(urlConvertida)

  } catch (erro) {
    console.log(erro)
  }
}
getAll();
```

On the server side I am passing in the API header the full access to the API as follows

```
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  app.use(cors());
  next();
});
```

Still I'm getting err
Does anyone have a hint of what it could be? Am I doing wrong on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: Please read [Is English required on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)  (tl;dr: It is). Other language versions of SO are available. Note to other SO users: [Do not translate this on behalf of the OP, if they can't ask the question in English, then they will struggle to respond to comments and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/19068).

Comment: Re edit: "Erro de CORS usando Fetch Api" isn't English

Comment: "Still I'm getting error" — What error?

Comment: `app.use(cors());` `app.use((req, res, next) => {` — Why are you using the CORS middleware from npm **and** rolling your own CORS middleware from scratch?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve
server side error, I added

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
```

and in the route add

```
.get('/assistencias', cors(), assistanceController.listarAssistencias)
```

Comment: If done correctly, the `app.use` statement will have already put the middleware in place for the route. You should **not** have to include it a second time.